# Unable to find where this middleware error is coming from

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, express-validator

I am getting a middleware is not a function error and I'm not sure why...

```
[Error] TypeError: middleware is not a function
```

Routes JS

```
import express from 'express'
import userController from '../../../server/src/controllers/user.controller.js'
import awaitHandlerFactory from '../../../server/src/middleware/awaitHandlerFactory.middleware.js'
export const router = express.Router();
import {auth} from '../middleware/auth.middleware.js'

import { createUserSchema, updateUserSchema, validateLogin } from '../middleware/validators/userValidator.middleware.js'

router.get('/get', auth(), awaitHandlerFactory(userController.getAllUsers))
router.post('/register', createUserSchema, awaitHandlerFactory(userController.createUser))
router.post('/login', validateLogin, awaitHandlerFactory(userController.userLogin))
```

Await handler.

```
export const awaitHandlerFactory = (middleware) => {
    return async(req, res, next) => {
        try {
            await middleware(req, res, next)
        }
        catch(err)
        {
            next(err)
        }
    }
}
```

the router.post('login') route is the one that doesn't work, both other routes work fine.

this is from the controller module.

```
    userLogin = async(req, res, next) => {
        this.checkValidation(req)

        const { email, password: pass} = req.body

        const user = await UserModel.findOne({ email })

        if(!user)
        {
            throw new HttpException(401, 'Unable to login.')
        }

        const isMatch = await bcrypt.compare(pass, user.password)

        if (!isMatch) {
            throw new HttpException(401, 'Incorrect password!')
        }

        const secretKey = process.env.SECRET_JWT || ""
        const token = jwt.sign({ user_id: user.id.toString() }, secretKey, {
            expiresIn: '24h'
        })

        const { password, ...userWithoutPassword } = user

        res.send({ ...userWithoutPassword, token})
    }
```

and this is the model module

```
    findOne = async (params) => {
        const {columnSet, values} = multipleColumnSet(params)

        const sql = `SELECT * FROM ${this.tableName} WHERE ${columnSet}`

        const result = await query(sql, [...values])

        return result[0]
    }
```

validateLogin

```
import { body } from 'express-validator';
import { Role } from '../../utility/userRoles.utility.js';


export const validateLogin = [
    body('email')
        .exists()
        .withMessage('Email is required')
        .isEmail()
        .withMessage('Must be a valid email')
        .normalizeEmail(),
    body('password')
        .exists()
        .withMessage('Password is required')
        .notEmpty()
        .withMessage('Password must be filled')
];
```

I can't even pin point where the error is coming from, this is the entire line of the error.

```
[Error] TypeError: middleware is not a function
```

```
 express:router dispatching POST /api/login +3s
  express:router query  : /api/login +1ms
  express:router expressInit  : /api/login +2ms
  express:router jsonParser  : /api/login +1ms
  express:router jsonParser  : /api/login +1ms
  express:router urlencodedParser  : /api/login +1ms
  express:router corsMiddleware  : /api/login +9ms
  express:router trim prefix (/api) from url /api/login +1ms
  express:router router /api : /api/login +0ms
  express:router dispatching POST /login +1ms
  express:router errorMiddleware  : /api/login +1ms
[Error] TypeError: middleware is not a function
```

Comment: Likely coming from this line: `await middleware(req, res, next)`. So one of your controller methods isn't a function.

Comment: I thought the same but even removing this entire line, also I use this on the router.post('register) and it works fine. So I'm really lost hah been on this for 4 hours now...

Comment: Does the error happen when you start the app, or only when a particular request comes in? You can run Express [in debug mode](https://expressjs.com/en/guide/debugging.html), which might also provide more information.

Comment: It only happens when the request comes in, I'll have a look at the debug mode now.

Comment: I have added the debug log to the question, tried to read through it but do not really understand what's going on there.

Comment: My guess is that `userController.userLogin` isn't a function. If you use a custom error handler in Express, either disable it or make sure it also logs `err.stack` instead of just the message.

Comment: please check if  userController.getAllUsers  is  a function.
awaitHandlerFactory is expecting a middleware function. make sure that "userController.getAllUsers" is a function

Comment: ShawonKanji this command works fine, it is the login part that doesn't seem to be working.@robertklep I rewrote the line of code in vs code and not it seems to not change colour so I'm guessing that you are right, however the other two functions are coming from the same class and they work so I'm not sure why the loginUser function is not registering.

Comment: @DMantas I couldn't say without seeing the controller module.

Comment: I have added the entire controller module in the main question.

Comment: I also added a photo of the vs code so you can see the color doesn't change for the userLogin function called on the rotue.

Comment: It's not really relevant what VSCode thinks. Also, I don't understand your code: you're importing `userController` (lower case 'u') yet exporting `UserController` (upper case 'U'). Also, you're using instance fields for all the functions (like `userLogin`) yet seemingly use them as _class_ fields (which won't work, they will be undefined, which explains why you're getting errors). Have you actually tested that the other routes work, or are you just going by what color VSCode is using for them?

Comment: I have tested the other routes and they do work, regarding your first point I have made the adjustment and now export and import them with same name. It was a typo. I don't know how I didn't get an error from that but it worked fine. How should I go about exporting these to the router if not in a class.

Comment: You can export them in a class if you prefix each function with `static` (to make it a class field), otherwise you can export an object that holds each function: `export UserController = { userLogin : async (…), }`

Comment: I have put static prefix to each of the functions but it doesn't seem to fix the issue, also the second option you mention I'm not really sure how to implement that as when I tried that format it doesn't work at all.

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out... after hours and hours. Basically I re-wrote the code because I made a messy version the first time. And for some reason VS-Code automatically linked the module from a whole different folder.

By the amount of the ../ it went out of the current directory into a whole other directory. That's why I couldn't use the userLogin function cause I hadn't got that far on the other version...

```
import userController from '../../../server/src/controllers/user.controller.js'
```